# компилятор ругается

Tags: php

попытался решить задачу не получилось, компилятор ругается,условия задачи:
Создайте функцию с названием countBasket, с одним параметром - массив позиций в корзине.

Функция должна посчитать и вернуть сколько всего в корзине товаров (в одной позиции корзины может быть несколько товаров - поле quantity).

В вашу функцию будут передавать массив следующей структуры:

task_1_08.png
количество позиций в корзине может быть от 0 до 10

```php
function countBasket($array = []): int
{
    $total = 0;
 
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($value['quantity'] < 10) {
            $total += $value['quantity'];
        }
    }
 
    return $total;
}
 
$basket = [
    [
        'position' => 'книга по php',
        'quantity' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'position' => 'Мышь беспроводная',
        'quantity' => 12,
    ],
];
 
echo countBasket($basket);
```

> Ошибка: Критическая ошибка выполнения кода: Return value of __PHPSandbox_b1b852e9972fcd749c8b2ba12169366e\countBasket() must be of the type integer, none returned

Comment: @Deniskoltsov всё [корректно работает](https://ideone.com/5TOegS), проблема в чем-то другом.

Comment: каким образом отформатировать?

Comment: @Эдуард компилятор онлайн в инете выдает ответ: 1, а компилятор на сайте где задание выполняю ругается

Comment: @Эдуард Ошибка: Критическая ошибка выполнения кода: Return value of __PHPSandbox_b1b852e9972fcd749c8b2ba12169366e\countBasket() must be of the type integer, none returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код, но уже отформатирован:

```php
<?php

function countBasket($array = []): int
{
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($value['quantity'] < 10) {
            $total += $value['quantity'];
        }
        return $total;
    }
}
```

И вот, сразу видно, что:

1. При пустом входящем массиве функция ничего не вернёт
2. Функция возвращает не общее количество элементов, а количество первого элемента, меньшее 10 либо 0.

А так же, стоит заметить, что 10 по условию задачи тоже должно быть включено.

А теперь просто выносим строку return из цикла...

```php
<?php

function countBasket($array = []): int
{
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($value['quantity'] <= 10) {
            $total += $value['quantity'];
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

... и код становится рабочим!

PS. Вы зря недооцениваете важность форматирования кода, его не зря придумали и вводят стандарты...

Comment: Спасибо  сработало , я просто  новичок  , поэтому  каких  то моментов не знаю, а где возможно  про стандарты почитать ? в документации php ? или еще литература есть?

Comment: Наиболее актуальный - [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/), его предшественники [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) и [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Comment: @Deniskoltsov Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его правильным

Comment: отметил ответ как правильный